# PHP / MySQL Frameworks for a basic CRM System

Tags: php, mysql, frameworks, crm

Perhaps, using the word CRM is a bit of a misnomer, essentially, I'm looking for a fast and easy way to create a front-end so that others in my organization can utilize a MySQL database that I've created that manages lists of respondents to marketing research surveys.

I would need to do the following through the proposed front-end:

1. Update/Add/Remove contact information
2. Add notes to a contact's "file"
3. Import/Export data from/to csv

My experience with PHP is not extensive so I would like something that is simple and straightforward (read: I'm not looking for something that tries to do everything or is over complicated).

An answer to this question will be accepted if you can outline the reason(s) for your recommendation.

**Database Schema:**

Table 1: Contact Information

```
ID, 
Name, address, email, etc...
```

Table 2: Surveys

```
Table 1 ID, 
Field 1,2,3,4,5 (Logicals 0/1)
```

Table 3: Notes

```
Table 1 ID,
Date, Note, etc...
```

Table 4: Select Survey Data Storage (Demos for easy survey sampling)

```
Table 1 ID, 
Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4...etc
```

Comment: Do you have your database scheme defined already, or will you be creating that as well?

Comment: @Micheal, I've updated the question with a short formed version of my current database structure.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not the place where someone do your homework!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One small framework comes to mind that will help make simple and secure user access and helps you update created database data without much hassel, it is called [flourishlib](http://flourishlib.com), I've often used and seen used with the small routing controller [Moor](http://github.com/jeffturcotte/moor).

This helps you with:

- Simple and safe user access. Supports ACL.
- CRUD.
- It has an ORM implementation, so you don't need to do much work in the data layer.
- Simple page templating.
- Posting and updating a record is as simple as `$record->populate` automatically taking values from a submitted form and populating values.
- Great dir and file handling. [Reading a CSV](http://flourishlib.com/docs/fFile#Iteration).

Check out the [how do I page](http://flourishlib.com/docs/HowDoI) for a quick look on how flourishlib solves common problems.

Update: I'm unsure how the ORM of flourishlib will match your database scheme without any configuration. If you have problems the support for flourish by the lead developer at the forums is great. Anyway you don't have to use the ORM. You could use flourishes fDatabase. Or you could use an other ORM entirely. Two I find interesting is:

- [Repose](http://repose-php.org/)
- [Outlet](http://www.outlet-orm.org/site/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Michael this one does seem to fit my needs quite well. And the example site is a helpful tool for "cut & paste" development.

Comment: You are welcome. For the reading of CSV see this part - http://flourishlib.com/docs/fFile#Iteration

Comment: Now, that's a useful tip. Thanks bunches.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you need framework? Your task is very simple and it can be easilly done without framework. Just organise files/folders layout, add some needed classes and you are good to go.

Comment: I agree. However, in the future it's highly probable that this will need to be able to scale substantially to perform other functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try [SugarCRM](http://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/)

It lacks a bit on documentation (mostly in the programming areas), but I think it will accomplish your goals.

Comment: I've reviewed SugarCRM in detail, installed it and played with it for a few days. Although it seems like this would fit my requirements, it's incredibly overloaded with other irrelevant features. Also, it seems a like this software is commercial hiding under the guise of being open source.

Comment: Yeah, that's one of it's problems. They say it's open source... but they don't really care for the users that use the version that is free. And yes I do think it's also bloated.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I actually went with Django. It's ridiculously easy to create database management edit/update/search tools using their ORM framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give a try to [Lime survey](http://www.limesurvey.com/).

It an open source application written in PHP with mySql as backend for survey development and managing samples.